# You don't seem to have a generator with the name angular installed.?

Tags: angularjs, generator, yeoman

fabian@fabian-SATELLITE-C660:/var/www/front-end/my-new-project$ yo angular
Error angular

You don't seem to have a generator with the name angular installed.
You can see available generators with npm search yeoman-generator and then install them with npm install [name].
To see the 0 registered generators run yo with the `--help` option.
fabian@fabian-SATELLITE-C660:/var/www/front-end/my-new-project$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> yo doctor a great helper:
>
> `fabian@fabian-SATELLITE-C660:/var/www/front-end/my-new-project$ yo doctor`
>
> `[Yeoman Doctor] Uh oh, I found potential errors on your machine`
>
> ---
>
> `[Error] NPM root value is not in your NODE_PATH
>        [info]
>          NODE_PATH = /usr/lib/nodejs:/usr/lib/node_modules:/usr/share/javascript
>          NPM root  = /home/fabian/npm/lib/node_modules`
>
> ```
>  [Fix] Append the NPM root value to your NODE_PATH variable
>    Add this line to your .bashrc
>      export NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:/home/fabian/npm/lib/node_modules
>    Or run this command
>      echo "export NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:/home/fabian/npm/lib/node_modules" >> ~/.bashrc > && source ~/.bashrc
> ```
>
> `fabian@fabian-SATELLITE-C660:/var/www/front-end/my-new-project$ echo "export >>    NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:/home/fabian/npm/lib/node_modules" >> ~/.bashrc > && source ~/.bashrc`
>
> `fabian@fabian-SATELLITE-C660:/var/www/front-end/my-new-project$ yo doctor
>      [Yeoman Doctor] Everything looks alright!`
>
> and now everything works:
>
> `fabian@fabian-SATELLITE-C660:/var/www/front-end/my-new-project$ yo angular`
>
> ```
>     _-----_
>    |       |    .--------------------------.
>    |--(o)--|    |    Welcome to Yeoman,    |
>   `---------´   |   ladies and gentlemen!  |
>    ( _´U`_ )    '--------------------------'
>    /___A___\    
>     |  ~  |     
>   __'.___.'__   
> ´   `  |° ´ Y `
> ```
>
> Out of the box I include Bootstrap and some AngularJS recommended modules.

Comment: This was the solution for me. I corrected my node path and updated npm like suggested and my generator was detected and it works after that.

Comment: same problem. But yo doctor says "everything is ok". Howto solve?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you installed with sudo, so:

```
sudo yo angular projectname
```